Is it possible to reference template template arguments?
I am experimenting with templates in C++ by implementing linear algebra library, thus this example might not be the best fit for the job.
Let's say that I have an N-dimensional container which contains data and common functions of vectors and matrices from which I want to inherit (I am aware, that it is a common practice to define Matrix type and then use using declaration for different linear algebra types like they do in eigen, but I want to inherit this container and then add methods to various types. Again, it might not be the best fit, but it is an experiment).
template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
class NDimContainer {
public:
    auto operator+=(const NDimContainer &other) {
        std::transform(elems.begin(), elems.end(), other.begin(), std::plus<T>());
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::array<T, (... * Dims)> elems;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Dims>
class Vector : public NDimContainer<T, Dims> { ... }

The question is: is it possible to access template arguments N and Dims... specified in the template template like this:
template <template<typename N, std::size_t... Dims> typename T>
require std::is_derived_from<NDimContainer<N, Dims...>, T<N, Dims...>>
auto operator+(const T &lhs, const T& rhs) { 
    return T { lhs } += rhs;
}

I know that it is possible do this:
template <template<typename, std::size_t...> typename T, typename N, std::size_t... Dims>
require std::is_derived_from<NDimContainer<N, Dims...>, T<N, Dims...>>
auto operator+(const T &lhs, const T& rhs) { ... }

But then the template won't get matched for e.g. Vector type (or at least in my case it didn't, if it is some trivial mistake, please correct me).
Is there any way to make this work so that I can do something like this?
Vector<int, 3> a = Vector<int, 3>() + Vector<int, 3>();

I have found previous questions about this topic here and here. But none of these really solves my use case.
The culprit that prohibits much simpler solution is Dims..., because I don't know how to do something like this:
template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
class A {
public:
    using Type = T;
    using Dimensions = Dims...; // Error
};

It probably could be possible to use std::integer_sequence, but that would introduce additional space costs which I don't want pay.
I have tried something like this:
template <template<typename N, std::size_t... Dims> typename T, typename NN = N, std::size_t... DDims = Dims>
require std::is_derived_from<NDimContainer<N, Dims...>, T<N, Dims...>>
auto operator+(const T &lhs, const T& rhs) { ... }

But that obviously also didn't work.
Is some similar construction possible?
edit: Adding minimal reproducible example
#include <array>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T, std::size_t ... Dims>
struct A {
    std::array<T,(Dims*...)> data = {};
    A& operator+=( const A& ) noexcept;
};

// This is the one I would like it matched instead, because then it would be instantiated for
// particular type.
template<template<typename N, std::size_t... Dims> typename T>
requires std::derived_from<A<N, Dims...>, T<N, Dims...>>
auto operator+(const A<N, Dims...>& lhs, const A<N, Dims...>& rhs) -> A<N, Dims...> {
    return A{lhs} += rhs;
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Vector : A<T,N> {
    using Base = A<T,N>;

    Vector() = default;
    Vector(const Base& base) : Base(base) {}
};

using Vector3d = Vector<double,3>;

int main() {
    Vector3d vec = Vector3d{} + Vector3d{};

    return 0;
}


"Is it possible to access template arguments N and Dims...." Nope.

Side note you might be interested in std::mdspan (C++23) or a (C++14/17 library implementation of that). Watch Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022

Also put together a [mcve] with all the #includes

"I probably could be possible to use std::integer_sequence, but that would introduce additional space costs" - using Dimensions = std::integer_sequence<Dims...>; doesn't take up any space

I have provided some minimal reproducible example, but this was rather theoretical question.
@TedLyngmo, honestly, I have not through about that and it might even solve my problem, great idea, I was locked on the idea of storing the sequence in a variable.

Always post complete error along with your question. Right now there are a lot of  mistakes in the code. Basically post a [mcve] that reproduces the said error instead of posting a code that compiles. I am trying  to solve the mistakes in the code but there seems to be too many silly mistakes. Like there is no is_derived_from in c++, Instead it should be derived_from

Alright, I have changed the example to look exactly how I have envisioned how the code could look like. But again, I do not really have problem with particular code piece. I was rather wondering whether it was possible to reference the template arguments N and Dims.

Your question is too long and there are too many questions in it. I will focus on this:

The question is: is it possible to access template arguments N and Dims... specified in the template template like this:
template <template<typename N, std::size_t... Dims> typename T>
require std::is_derived_from<NDimContainer<N, Dims...>, T<N, Dims...>>
auto operator+(const T &lhs, const T& rhs) { 
    return T { lhs } += rhs;
}


No. Here template <template<typename N, std::size_t... Dims> typename T> you are saying that T is a template with parameters N, and Dims.... You can instantiate T, but you cannot deduce from T the values of N and Dims... because they are parameters.
What you are asking is similar to: "Given a function f that takes a int x as parameter, can I find out what the value of x is?". Of course not. f is a function to which any x can be passed.
I sense a pointless use of template template argument like I have seen it before. I suppose you actually want a type and something like this:
 template <typename T>
 require std::is_derived_from<NDimContainer<T>,T>
 auto operator+(const T &lhs, const T& rhs) { 
     return T { lhs } += rhs;
 }

Where T is an instantiation of some template that had parameters N and Dims... If that is the case, then you can deduce from that instantiation T (a type), the parameters N and Dim..., such that T is the same type as some U<N,Dims...>. That is possible, but a different question.

Sorry, for the unclear question, but you have chosen the right one and to look on the template parameters like if they are function parameters helped me get the idea why it does not work. I think that it is a shame, because it looked good to me, therefore I was wondering why it does not work. Thank you for your answer.

You can write a trait for what you are checking.
The primary template is a type deriving std::false_type
template<typename T> 
struct IsNDimContainer : std::false_type {};

Then there is a partial specialisation for types of the form C<T, Dims...>, which checks if NDimContainer<T, Dims> is a base.
template<template<typename, std::size_t...> typename C, typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
struct IsNDimContainer<C<T, Dims...>> : std::is_base_of<NDimContainer<T, Dims...>, C<T, Dims...>> {};

Which you can then use
template <typename T>
requires IsNDimContainer<T>
auto operator+(const T &lhs, const T& rhs) { 
    return T { lhs } += rhs;
}

However if you have C++23, you can do binary operators in class, using an explicit object parameter to get the right type.
template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
class NDimContainer {
public:
    template<typename Self>
    Self& operator+=(this Self& self, const Self& other) {
        std::transform(self.elems.begin(), self.elems.end(), other.begin(), std::plus<T>());
        return *self;
    }
    template<typename Self>
    Self operator+(this Self self, const Self& other) {
        return self += other;
    }
private:
    std::array<T, (... * Dims)> elems;
};


nice. This is what I wanted to add to my answer, because I felt it was missing, and more.
